# How to get name of folders only in PHP?

Tags: php

I am using this code to list the name of ll existing Folders in a Directory but it is returning all folders, images, files (everything) in the directory.

```
<?php
// open this directory 
$myDirectory = opendir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/.");
$list = 0;

while (false !== ($entryName = readdir($myDirectory))) {
if ($entryName != "." && $entryName != ".." && $entryName != ".DS_Store") {
$dirArray[] = $entryName;
}

}
```

How can I modify it to get ONLY Folders Name in the directory?

Comment: thanks str, I tried this already like this way 'if (is_dir($entryName)) {
$dirArray[] = $entryName;} but I got empty dots instead of the file names and the inks also didn't work

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What are "empty dots"? Why should there be file names if you only want directories? And your code does not include any type of "links".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
<?php
$foldersandfiles = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/.");

foreach( $foldersandfiles as $folderorfile ) {
    if( $folderorfile != '.' && $folderorfile != '..' && is_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . $folderorfile) ) {
        $dirArray[] = $folderorfile;
    }
}
```

Please give it a go.

Comment: Thanks Joans, This is what I was looking for it